# Print specific child firebase db

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following database layout:

```
-PGroups
   -Date
      -GameTime
         -Entry Cost
```

I know you can use the following to print out everything in PGroups

```
ref.child("PGroups").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

                    //makes sure there are public
                    if (snapshot.hasChildren()){
                        print(snapshot.childrenCount) // I got the expected number of items
                        let enumerator = snapshot.children
                        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as! FIRDataSnapshot {
                            print(rest.value)
                        }
```

Is there a way to just print out the "GameTime" Level children, or just the "Date" Children?

Answer (score 0):

You can try making a dictionary out of the data's children, something like this might work.

```
ref.child("PGroups").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

   if let snapValue = snapshot.value as [String : [String : String]]{
      // Here try printing out the dictionary and seeing how to correctly get the right value out.
   }
```

I'm a little confused about your database structure but you might have to create a dictionary one level deeper if this doesnt work, i.e. `[String : [String : [String : String]]]`. If you give a more detailed picture of the structure I could better help you get out the value you want.